# Multiple shifts on dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to repeatedly shift select columns of a a dataframe based on the number of shifts specified in array nShiftsPerCol.  How to generate the output dataframe DFO that contains the columns with nonzero shifts specified and each of those columns shifted multiple times.  Note, the first shift is zero or no shift.  Append the shift number to the column name.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'C': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]})
print(df)
nCols = df.shape[0]
nShiftsPerCol = np.zeros(nCols)
nShiftsPerCol[0]=3 # shift column A 3 times
nShiftsPerCol[2]=2 # shift column C 2 times
```

Original dataframe

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  3  4
2  3  4  5
3  4  5  6
4  5  6  7
```

Desired output

```
   A_0  A_1  A_2  C_0   C_1
0  1    2    3    3     4
1  2    3    4    4     5
2  3    4    5    5     6
3  4    5    NA   6     7
4  5    NA   NA   7     NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create `Series` with filtering out `0` values:

```
#for columns need shape[1]
nCols = df.shape[1]
nShiftsPerCol = np.zeros(nCols)
nShiftsPerCol[0]=3 # shift column A 3 times
nShiftsPerCol[2]=2 # shift column C 2 times

print (nShiftsPerCol)

s = pd.Series(nShiftsPerCol, df.columns).astype(int)
s = s[s!=0]
print (s)
A    3
C    2
dtype: int32
```

and then loop and create new columns:

```
for i, x in s.items():
    for y in range(x):
        df['{}_{}'.format(i, y)] = df[i].shift(-y)

print (df)
   A  B  C  A_0  A_1  A_2  C_0  C_1
0  1  2  3    1  2.0  3.0    3  4.0
1  2  3  4    2  3.0  4.0    4  5.0
2  3  4  5    3  4.0  5.0    5  6.0
3  4  5  6    4  5.0  NaN    6  7.0
4  5  6  7    5  NaN  NaN    7  NaN
```

Another solution for store columns names and shift number is list of tuples:

```
L = list(zip(df.columns, nShiftsPerCol.astype(int)))
L = [x for x in L if x[1] != 0]
print (L)
[('A', 3), ('C', 2)]

for i, x in L:
    for y in range(x):
        df['{}_{}'.format(i, y)] = df[i].shift(-y)

print (df)
   A  B  C  A_0  A_1  A_2  C_0  C_1
0  1  2  3    1  2.0  3.0    3  4.0
1  2  3  4    2  3.0  4.0    4  5.0
2  3  4  5    3  4.0  5.0    5  6.0
3  4  5  6    4  5.0  NaN    6  7.0
4  5  6  7    5  NaN  NaN    7  NaN
```

Comment: This is very close to what I need, except I need the output in a new dataframe DFO, without the original columns.  I also need the original dataframe.

Comment: I added the line dfo = df before the loop, and the line dfo.drop(dfo.columns[0:nCols], axis=1, inplace=True) after the loop

Comment: Or you can use `df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)` before loop and in loop change `df['{}_{}'.format(i, y)] = df[i].shift(-y)` to `df1['{}_{}'.format(i, y)] = df[i].shift(-y)
`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
from itertools import chain
nShiftsPerCol = [3, 0, 2]
# define a function to help generate shifted columns
col_maker = lambda df, x, num: df[x].shift(-num)
# generate new_cols from nShiftPerCol
new_cols = chain(*[[(df.columns[idx], i) for i in range(v)] 
                   for idx, v in enumerate(nShiftsPerCol) if v != 0])
# output of new_cols
# [('A', 0), ('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('C', 0), ('C', 1)] 
df_desired = pd.DataFrame({col + "_" + str(num): col_maker(df, col, num) 
                           for col, num in new_cols})
```